# Would Pot of Extravagance be too unfair if you use a deck that doesn't use an Extra Deck?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Pot of Extravagance](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Pot_of_Extravagance) allows you to banish cards from your Extra Deck to draw cards.

However, some archetypes, like "Monarch", "True Draco" or the "Lair of Darkness" structure deck doesn't need an Extra Deck to beat an opponent.

*If you use one of these types of decks, could you just put "useless" cards in your Extra Deck that you don't plan on using so there is no cost to using Pot of Extravagance?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use one of these types of decks, could you just put "useless" cards in your Extra Deck that you don't plan on using so there is no cost to using Pot of Extravagance?

**Yes you can.**

You can build your deck and extra deck the way you want, as long as you stick to the current [Banlist](https://www.yugioh-card.com/en/limited/) (on an official game, that is) and the game rules.

Comment: I would be carefull about using that strategy. I'm not sure if sanctions were issued, but I remember a case of someone placing a face up card on their extra deck to mislead his opponent, but it wasn't allowed by the judges.

Comment: Deleted the anectode to avoid it distracting from the core answer